# Object Serialization to Dictionary per propertyname

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, deserialization

I asking this mostly to see if there is something that ressembles what I am trying to achive.

My ultimate goal is to serialize an object graph, keeping references, but making all the properties accessible via a Path of sorts.

My first thoughts were something like  dictionary and recursively loop through all the objects properties/fields, and if the value is different than the Default one, try and serialize if its a primitive, otherwise keep going till the type can be serialized.

I need to support Types not marked as `[Serializable]`, and to be able to add custom serialization, similiar to how surrugates work in the `BinaryFormatter`.

Is there a serializer that works remotely like I said?
Or what other caveats can you think of, by this aproach?

Note: The serialization Size is *not* a big issue nor is the *speed* that it serializes/deserializes, at least for now.

An example of what I want to to is something like this :
`SerializationContext.GetValue["root/Prop/X"]` returns me the `X` value.

This needs to work with .Net 3.5, and it should serialize based on field/property name.

Comment: Have you checked [XML Path Language (XPath)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256115(v=vs.110).aspx)? It's used to write queries for XML documents, but it also supports [more complex queries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086(v=vs.110).aspx) than the one you've shown.

Comment: Serialization doesn't work for all structures.  You can create you own XML to meet your needs.

Comment: Json.NET supports [Preserving object references](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/preserveobjectreferences.htm). [Querying JSON with JSONPath expressions](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectTokenJsonPath.htm), and [Custom converters for manual serialization](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm).  Is that what you want?